# Why does the Unique keywords cause a mismatch between synthesis and simulation

Tags: system-verilog

I was setting my my environment for my second course in SystemVerilog at Uni. I wanted to look into a linter when I noticed svlint has a rule which forbids the usage of the unique keyword because

> this causes mismatch between simulation and synthesis

[svlint rules](https://github.com/dalance/svlint/blob/master/RULES.md)

why is this true? I can't imagine why it might cause differences or why it should be avoided. I've always found the unique keyword useful in ensuring full coverage.

Comment: To hazard a guess, it may because the simulated and synthesized results may differ in the undefined case where there are multiple matches. The simulated case will only execute the first match, but the synthesized case may execute multiple.

Comment: @Brian, But that is The Whole point of the `unique` keyword. You get an simulation error if there are multiple matches

Comment: You also get a run-time error if there are no matches. Someone did a bad job adding this rule to the svlint.

Comment: I looked at those rules. They claim mismatches between simulation and synthesis and show non-synthesizable code in examples. The developers apparently do not understand verilog.